# How do I create an ixbrl file with xsd or xbrl?

Tags: xml, xsd, xbrl

I want to convert an xsd or xbrl file to ixbrl, but I didn't find the right solution

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for doesn't really make sense.

An XSD file is an XML Schema document.  It defines the structure of an XML document, and so contains a different type of information to an XBRL or iXBRL report.

An XBRL report contains tagged data.  An iXBRL report is an HTML file with XBRL tags embedded in it, so whilst you can extract XBRL data from an iXBRL, you cannot convert an XBRL report into an iXBRL report.

There are tools that will generate a rendering of an XBRL report, and such a rendering could be saved as an iXBRL report, this isn't really the point of iXBRL, which is to allow the preparers to retain control over the presentation of their reports.

You can read more about iXBRL [here](https://www.xbrl.org/the-standard/what/ixbrl/).

Comment: How do I generate an ixbrl file?